# Scraping a webpage with multiple tabs in R -- Can't access tables

Tags: r, web-scraping

I've looked through a bunch of the stackoverflow questions regarding similar issues but I'm stumped and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried to both view the page source and find the table I want as well as use the SelectorGadget tool to find the elements that I'm trying to scrape and nothing seems to get me what I want.

Here is the closest I've gotten:

I'm trying to scrape the offensive and defensive stats from the Offense and Defense tabs of this page (and all subsequent games after this page):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
url <- read_html("https://stats.xfl.com/1")
```

Looking at the html nodes I've gotten this output:

```
tbls <- html_nodes(url, "#gameStats")
tbls

{xml_nodeset (6)}
[1] <div id="gameStats" data-bind="visible: vmTeamStats.isVisible">\r\n      <div class="statDi ...
[2] <div id="gameStats" data-bind="visible: vmOffensiveStats.isVisible">\r\n\r\n      <div clas ...
[3] <div id="gameStats" data-bind="visible: vmDefensiveStats.isVisible">\r\n      <div class="s ...
[4] <div id="gameStats" data-bind="visible: vmPlayListStats.isVisible">\r\n      <div class="st ...
[5] <div id="gameStats" data-bind="visible: vmPlayListStats.isScoringVisible">\r\n      <!-- ko ...
[6] <div id="gameStats" data-bind="visible: vmPossessionStats.isVisible">\r\n      <div class=" ...
```

This seems to get me close, as now I can see each table in this list. However, I can't figure out the next step to, for example, select the Rushing, Passing, and Receiving tables for the respective visitor and home teams.

I've tried to look at what tables are in the offensive tab but I get the following error:

```
tbls %>% 
  .[2] %>% 
  html_table()

Error in html_table.xml_node(X[[i]], ...) : 
  html_name(x) == "table" is not TRUE
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing incorrectly and how I can make it work?

Comment: One thought: go to the dev console of your browser when you're looking at it interactively, and see what's happening when you change tabs. My guess is that it's doing a live-query or live-update, in which case it's doing "lazy" stuff on the not-visible tabs. If you see this activity, look at the URLs being queried in the background, you might not be able get to it from the original website, instead just using `jump_to` or similar. If that doesn't work ... perhaps `RSelenium` is a feasible option, though it's a bit more to control (and often very time-sensitive).

Comment: Thanks. That was my first though. I had done that but the URL stays static. It seems like the tabs are occurring within that page?

Comment: The URL in the browser url-bar should not necessarily change, it's what is going on under the hood that is eye-opening. Are you using the dev-console? (On FF, press `Ctrl-Shift-I`, then click on "Network" and then reload the page.)

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the dev-console checked out the Network and refreshed the page. I see what you mean. It looks like everything is loaded as a .js file. I'm trying to figure out what the correct path and way forward is to access the data still.